# Laravel model returns empty array only from guzzle request

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I have 2 laravel projects where the first project is providing data for my second project.
it works fine when I tried to send request to my first project using Postman, but it always return an empty array using my second project. the first project:

```
route::get('/users',function(){
  return response()->json(User::all());
})
```

Postman result:

```
 [{id: 1, nama: "Idris Akbar Adyusman", email: "asd@asd.asd", email_verified_at: null, hp: null,…}]
```

However my second laravel project using guzzle Http client:

```
[]
```

here is the code for the client

```
return Http::get('http://first.test/api/users');
```

Comment: What do you get if you `dd(Http::get('http://first.test/api/users'));`?

Comment: Does your postman request set any headers? Your `Http` request does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your response as **json**. Below code may help you

```
return Http::get('http://first.test/api/users')->json();
```

You can get more info about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests)